# How to print 100 values which are divisible by 3 and 5?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lower = int(input("Enter lower range limit:"))
upper = int(input("Enter upper b range limit:"))
Count = 0
for i in range(lower, upper+1):
    if((i%3==0) & (i%5==0)):
    Count += 1
    print(count)
```

I want to print 100 values which are divisible by 3 and 5, but in count only 7 is showing, can anyone suggest what to do, it will be appreciated!

Comment: There are only 7 values that satisfy your condition between 1 and 100. You should not limit your search in a `for` loop, but use `while` that loops until `count` is equal to `upper`. Also `&` is not what you think it is in Python.

Comment: @Selcuk can u show how to implement and while and count to print 100 values?

Comment: Someone else has already posted a proper answer, but if you don't know how to implement a `while` loop I recommend you to go back to your Python tutorial.

Comment: @Selcuk i run the loop for 1 to 100 only 7 values but  i want to print 100 values  in nterms  which are divisible by 3 and 5 .

Comment: `print(*range(0, 1500, 15))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
num = int(input("How many Numbers you want :"))

i=0
Count = 0
while(Count != num):
    if((i%3==0) and (i%5==0)):
        Count += 1
        print(i)
    i = i + 1

print("Count is :",Count)
```

Comment: `while` and `if` are not functions so you can drop the extra parentheses. `while(Count != num):` should be `while Count != num:` and `if((i%3==0) and (i%5==0)):` should be `if (i%3==0) and  (i%5==0):` (or even `if i % 3 == 0 and  i % 5 == 0:`).

Comment: yeh, you are correct. but this parentheses helps to identify condition. and makes easy to understand for new devs.

Answer (score -1):

## Python program to print all the numbers

## divisible by 3 and 5 for a given number

## Result function with N

def result(N):

```
# iterate from 0 to N
for num in range(N):
    
        # Short-circuit operator is used
        if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0:
            print(str(num) + " ", end = "")
            
        else:
            pass
```

## Driver code

if **name** == "**main**":

```
# input goes here
N = 100

# Calling function
result(N)
```